# Fixed point question with convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, cauchy-sequences

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is $C^1$ and $1$ to $1$ and there exists a strict increasing sequence $t_{n} \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $f^{t_{n}}(x) \to p$ for all $x$ as $n\to \infty$ (composition $t_{n}$ times) where $p$ is a fixed point, i.e $f(p)=p$. Can you prove or find a counterexample that $f^n(x) \to p$ as $n \to \infty$ for all $x$.

Comment: Is the statement "if $f^{t_n}(x) \to p$ for every $x$, then $f^n(x) \to p$ for every $x$", or "if a particular $x$ satisfies $f^{t_n}(x) \to p$, then $f^n(x) \to p$"?

Comment: For all $x$. Fixed it

Answer (score 0):

If you can prove that $Df(p)=0$ (which intuitively seems true to me, though I can't think of how to prove it), the result follows:

Suppose the statement is false, so there exists $x \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $f^n(x) \not\to p$. So there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $f^n(x)$ is not eventually in the neighbourhood $B(p,\epsilon)$. Then, since $f^{t_n}(x) \to p$, for each $n \in \mathbb N$ (large enough that $1/n < \epsilon$), there is some $m$ such that $f^m(x) \in B(p,1/n)$ but $f^{m+1}(x) \notin B(p,1/n)$; let $x_n := f^m(x)$. Hence we have a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n \to p$, and $||x_n-p|| < ||f(x_n)-p||$ for each $n$. But then, since $Df(p) = 0$, we have (by replacing $h$ with $p-x_n$ in the derivative limit):
\begin{align*}
0 &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{||f(p-h) - f(p) - 0h||}{||h||} \\
  &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{||f(x_n) - p||}{||p-x_n||} \\
  &\geq 1 && \text{since $||x_n-p|| < ||f(x_n)-p||$}
\end{align*}
A contradiction, so the statement is true.

Comment: This is wrong. The Jacobian does not have to be 0. You have not used even the fact that $f$ is 1-1.